# NSTableView and scrolling background NSColor : Automatic Elasticity Color

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview

I have succesfully changed the background `NSColor` of my `NSTableView` using `setBackgroundColor:` for both the `NSTableView` and the `NSCell` (using `tableView: willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`). Now, I would like the background to also have this color when scrolling out (either top or bottom), which is currently white as pictured below.

[image]

I found this link which seems to indicate the need to subclass `NSTableView` and implement 
`- (void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect`, any suggestion on that ?

Source : [Themeing NSTableView](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/themeing-nstableview/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer at the question by looking at the header file for the NSTableView class `NSTableView.h` and found a mention to this method :

```
/* Override to customize background drawing.
*/
- (void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect;
```

I then subclassed NSTableView and overrode the previous method :

```
@implementation MyColoredTableView

/**
 Sets the color of the background for elastic scrollers
*/
- (void)drawBackgroundInClipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor]set];    //Set your color here
    NSRectFill(clipRect);
}

@end
```

Change the class of your `NSTableView` in InterfaceBuilder to `MyColoredTableView`, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

### > Now, I would like the background to also have this color when > scrolling out (either top or bottom),

For this you need to have one method which will called when you scroll your scroll view. So for that just include this notification below:-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

// This notification will called when you scroll your scrollview
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(boundsDidChange:) name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification 
object:[yourScrollView contentView]];
}

-(void)boundsDidChange:(NSNotification*)not
{
//Write your code for changing background colors of tableview
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the actual drawing code, what would it be ? I reckon it involves calculating the "overflow" of the view and filling the rectangle with the proper color, but I can't implement it properly.

Comment: How you are implementing??